# How can I fix button on the bottom of the view when scrolling vertically on device?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, scrollview, xamarin.forms

I have followed Gusman's advice and I positioned by layout in this order:

```
->StackLayout, VerticalOptions=FillAndExpand
  ->ScrollView, VerticalOptions=FillAndExpand
    ->RelativeLayout
    ->StackLayout
    ->StackLayout
  ->Button, VerticalOptions=EndAndExpand
```

Where I want my Button to be fixed on the bottom of my device view when scrolling throughout the whole layout. However, the view does not show the redeem button nor the full scroll bar. I'm not sure why those two elements are not displaying on the view.

How can I fix button on the bottom of the view when scrolling vertically on device?

Here's my latest code:

```
public StackLayout OffersSlideViewCarouselChild(Offer offer)
{
    Image productImage = new Image
    {
        Source = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri(offer.Image.Replace("https://", "http://"))),
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand, 
        HeightRequest = 300, 
        WidthRequest = 300,
        Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit
    };

    var topStackLayout = new StackLayout
    {
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center, 
    };
    topStackLayout.Children.Add(productImage);

    StackLayout contentStackLayout = new StackLayout
    {
        Padding = new Thickness(16, 16, 16, 10),
        Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
    };
    var savedBtn = SavedButtonLayout(offer.IsSelected, offer.Id);
    var redeemBtn = RedeemBtnLayout(offer.Id);
    var timeRemainingLabel = TimeRemainingLayout(offer, offer.Id);

    contentStackLayout.Children.Add(new UILabel(16) {
        Text = offer.ProductName,
        TextColor = ColorHelper.FromHex(CoreTheme.COLOR_OFFERCELL_PRODUCT_TEXT),
        FontFamily = CoreTheme.FONT_FAMILY_DEFAULT_BOLD
    });

    contentStackLayout.Children.Add(new UILabel(14) {
        Text = offer.LongRewardsMessage,
        TextColor = ColorHelper.FromHex(CoreTheme.COLOR_DEAL_PAGE_LONG_REWARD_MESSAGE_RED),
        FontFamily = CoreTheme.FONT_FAMILY_DEFAULT_BOLD

    });

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(offer.PowerMessage)) {
        var htmlText = string.Format("<html><body style='color:#9b9b9b'>{0}</body></html>", offer.PowerMessage.Replace(@"\", string.Empty));

        var browser = new WebView() {
            HeightRequest = (DeviceDisplaySettings.defaultheight > 600) ? 240 : 150,
            Source = new HtmlWebViewSource() { Html = htmlText },
        };
        browser.Navigating += OnNavigating;

        contentStackLayout.Children.Add(browser);
    }

    var mainRelLayout = new RelativeLayout();

    mainRelLayout.Children.Add(savedBtn,
        xConstraint: Constraint.Constant(0),
        yConstraint: Constraint.Constant(0),
        widthConstraint: Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) =>
        {
            return parent.Width;
        }),
        heightConstraint: Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) =>
        {
            return 40;
        })
        );


    mainRelLayout.Children.Add(topStackLayout,
        Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) => { return (parent.Width - productImage.Width) / 2; }), 
        Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) => { return parent.Y; })
    );

    mainRelLayout.Children.Add(timeRemainingLabel,
        null,
        Constraint.RelativeToView(topStackLayout, (parent, sibling) => { return sibling.Height; })
        );

    mainRelLayout.Children.Add(contentStackLayout,
        null,
        Constraint.RelativeToView(topStackLayout, (parent, sibling) => { return sibling.Height; })
    );


    var mainScrollView = new ScrollView()
    {
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
        Orientation = ScrollOrientation.Vertical,
        WidthRequest = DeviceDisplaySettings.defaultwidth,
        HeightRequest = DeviceDisplaySettings.defaultheight,
        Content = mainRelLayout
    };

    var mainStackLayout = new StackLayout()
    {
        Spacing = 0,
        Padding = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0),
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
        Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,
        Children = { mainScrollView, redeemBtn }

    };

    return mainStackLayout;
}
```

Comment: Some aclaration, you want to add the relativeLayout inside an scroll view or add an scroll view to the relative layout?

Comment: I have a relative layout but I want to make the whole view scrollable horizontally. Does that make sense? So probably scrollview to the relative layout? Is that right? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at the wireframe you provided (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYydg.jpg), this is what I would use

*(note that I am using XAML here to make the visual structure more obvious)*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="FormsSandbox.XamlPage">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ScrollView Orientation="Vertical">

            <!---Using StackLayout here to make sure scrolling works as
                 expected - but put your RelativeLayout content here instead -->
            <StackLayout Spacing="0">
                <BoxView BackgroundColor="Red" HeightRequest="50"/>
                <BoxView BackgroundColor="Yellow" HeightRequest="100"/>
                <BoxView BackgroundColor="Red" HeightRequest="50"/>
                <BoxView BackgroundColor="Yellow" HeightRequest="100"/>
                <BoxView BackgroundColor="Red" HeightRequest="50"/>
                <BoxView BackgroundColor="Yellow" HeightRequest="100"/>
                <BoxView BackgroundColor="Red" HeightRequest="50"/>
                <BoxView BackgroundColor="Yellow" HeightRequest="100"/>
                <BoxView BackgroundColor="Red" HeightRequest="50"/>
                <BoxView BackgroundColor="Yellow" HeightRequest="100"/>
                <BoxView BackgroundColor="Red" HeightRequest="50"/>
                <BoxView BackgroundColor="Yellow" HeightRequest="100"/>
                <BoxView BackgroundColor="Red" HeightRequest="50"/>
            </StackLayout>

        </ScrollView>

        <Button Grid.Row="1" Text="REDEEM"/>
    </Grid>

</ContentPage>
```

[image: Running the above layout on iOS]

Comment: Could you take a look at the updated post? my redeem button doesn't show up on my view.

Comment: Your StackLayout is now larger than the screen according to your updated code. Your ScrollView is given a width/height request equal to device screen size, and then the button is placed below that inside of a StackLayout that will expand to accommodate it. Therefore, the button is probably below the bottom of the screen.

Comment: It might make it easier to help you if you can provide a wireframe of what your goal is

Comment: How do I fix the scrollview so that the button appears on the device screen? I would need to restrict scrollview to height - button.height? I'll update the post with where I am and problems I face in a little bit. Thanks.  But basically think of a view with a bunch of stacklayouts and a button at the bottom of the screen that is fixed and when you scroll through the stacked layout, the button stays fixed on the bottom. Thanks! Oh one more thing, the button should be on top of the scrollview if space is needed.

Comment: here's a mockup of what I'm trying to achieve: imgur.com/wWBUNud. I also updated my post. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, the wireframe was useful. This can be done with a StackLayout, but my preference is to use a Grid because it is more flexible and makes it a little more clear (IMO). I've updated the answer again to show this.

Comment: I'm so sorry to waste your time on this but thank you so much for your help. I started a new post on update on where I am: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36463085/scrollview-contents-get-cut-off-the-view I think your insights could be useful since you mentioned something about the button being cut off from my view? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I had to use a grid and set the parameters above.

Answer (score 0):

For the aclaration I understand you want something like this:

```
->ScrollView
  ->RelativeLayout
    ->StackLayout
    ->StackLayout
    ->Button
```

But want to fix the button on the bottom even when the page is scrolled.

With that structure is just impossible to do it but it's very easy to fix it with an structure like this:

```
->StackLayout, VerticalOptions=FillAndExpand
  ->ScrollView, VerticalOptions=FillAndExpand
    ->RelativeLayout
      ->StackLayout
      ->StackLayout
  ->Button, VerticalOptions=EndAndExpand
```

With that structure you will have a root StackLayout where you nest an ScrollView which will fill all the screen except for the space taken by the Button which will stick to the bottom of the screen.

Hope it makes sense.

Cheers.

Comment: I'll give it a try but what if the button is inside a stack Layout?

Comment: you want the button to stick at the bottom, so you need to position it somehwere outside the scroll layout below it, if you surround the button with another StackLayout it will do nothing while you add it below the scrollview (unless you want to add more sticky stuff on the bottom of the page, but it's just adding another unneeded container, the root stack layout will allow you to do that).

Comment: I have one more question, ScrollView does not containa definition for "Children"... that is if I want to add the relative layout to ScrollView as a child. How do I do that?

Comment: "Children" property only exists on containers which allow multiple objects to be added as child, ScrollView only allows one item and the property for that is "Content".

Comment: Well if I use Content, I get: can't initialize type "view" with a collection initializer because does not implement IEnumerable. Inside scrollview, I am setting  Content = { mainRelLayout }

Comment: Just set Content = mainRelLayout, the property is a View not an array of views.

Comment: I made the necessary changes but my redeem button and the scrollview for the whole page is not implemented. I can't see button on my view.

Comment: why are the StackLayouts not nested in the Relative Layout above in your example? Thanks!

Comment: Because the formatting was wrong, sorry, updated it.

Comment: updated post. The scroll bar and button are not visible on view following this approach